# Using purrr or across with mutate to generate columns based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

There are many Q&As concerning the use of `purrr` package functions with `mutate`, but I haven't found one that I can apply to my particular situation, which involves a conditional function. Here's an example with a toy dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(year = c("2018", "2018", "2019", "2019"), 
             observed = c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES"))
```

Here's the desired output:

```
df %>% mutate(observed_2018 = if_else(observed == "YES" & year == "2018", 1, 0), 
              observed_2019 = if_else(observed == "YES" & year == "2019", 1, 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   year  observed observed_2018 observed_2019
#>   <chr> <chr>            <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 2018  YES                  1             0
#> 2 2018  NO                   0             0
#> 3 2019  NO                   0             0
#> 4 2019  YES                  0             1
```

How can I programmatically generate **observed_2018** and **observed_2019** using a `purrr` function (or, alternatively, `across()`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `map_dfc()` to column-bind the output of each year and unnest the list-column with `tidyr::unnest()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(obs = map_dfc(set_names(2018:2019), ~ +(observed == "YES" & year == .x))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(obs, names_sep = '_')
```

If you don't want to use an additional package (`tidyr`), you could just column-bind the output of `map_dfc` and the original data `df`.

```r
bind_cols(
  df,
  map_dfc(2018:2019, ~ transmute(df, 'obs_{.x}' := +(observed == "YES" & year == .x)))
)
```

An alternative of `map` is `reduce()` from the same package.

```r
reduce(2018:2019,
  ~ mutate(.x, 'obs_{.y}' := +(observed == "YES" & year == .y)), .init = df
)
```

---

###### Output

```
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   year  observed obs_2018 obs_2019
#   <chr> <chr>       <int>    <int>
# 1 2018  YES             1        0
# 2 2018  NO              0        0
# 3 2019  NO              0        0
# 4 2019  YES             0        1
```

Comment: These are great solutions. Is it possible to use `reduce()` in a pipeline starting with `df %>%`?

Comment: @nicholas yes, `df %>% reduce(2018:2019, ~ mutate(.x, 'obs_{.y}' := +(observed == "YES" & year == .y)), .init = .)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data.table approaches

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
yrs = unique(df$year)
```

then, you can either use `set()` like this:

```
for(y in yrs) set(df,j=paste0("observed_",y),value = 1*(df$observed=="YES" & df$year==y))
```

or you can use `lapply()` in `j` like this:

```
df[, paste0("observed_",yrs):=lapply(yrs, \(y) 1*(observed=="YES" & year==y))]
```

both give the same output:

```
   year observed observed_2018 observed_2019
1: 2018      YES             1             0
2: 2018       NO             0             0
3: 2019       NO             0             0
4: 2019      YES             0             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
cbind(df,  model.matrix(~ year - 1, df) * (df$observed == 'YES'))
  year observed year2018 year2019
1 2018      YES        1        0
2 2018       NO        0        0
3 2019       NO        0        0
4 2019      YES        0        1
```